# How to use mailto on a self-submit form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, mailto

I have to make modifications on an existing code and I am struggling with the mailto function. I would like that when I submit my form, a pre-populated mail opens with Outlook (or any other mailer configured) so the user can check if anything is fine and then submit the mail with the form's data.

I want to use `mailto:` because at the moment the page (that is on a local server, not on internet) only works on IE (the last developer used ActiveX Data Object and it doesn't work on Edge/Chrome/Firefox).

I've already tried putting the `mailto:` in the form's `action` tag, it didn't work, I tried some javascript too and the same happened. Also, my form submits to itself with the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` global variable.

The form/code is big so I'll only put the part that might be useful for you to help me.

**Here's the form I use :**

```
echo "<FORM action=". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . " name=\"form\" method=\"POST\">";
"my form here"
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Envoyer\" value=\"Send\"/>";
echo "</FORM>";
```

Then, I want to get the data from the form and open a mailer when the user hit the submit button with a pre-populated mail with data in it.

**Here's what I use :**

```
echo "<script>
    var email = $maildest;
    var subject = \"Request of the user\";
    var emailBody = $MAIL;
    window.location = \"mailto:\"+email+\"?subject=\"+subject+\"&body=\"+emailBody;";
    echo "</script>";
echo "An OUTLOOK window opened with the informations you entered. <br/>Send the email so we can take it into account.<br/>
exit(0);
```

I don't have any error message, the page works just fine but when I hit the submit button nothing happens, not even the mailer opening a window or anything else. I'm sure there is something I'm missing and I'm a bit rusty with php/html/javascript so I came here seeking your help.

Comment: So the obvious issue is you do not have the vars in the last line `window.location = \`mailto:?subject=&body=\`;`  it should look like 
`window.location = \`mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${emailBody}\``;

Comment: You need to use single quotes in the echo in the last line `echo 'window.location = \`mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${emailBody}\`;';`

Comment: Oh yeah now it works.. I feel dumb lmao.. I knew it was about quotes and stuff, this thing is hard when you don't code that often.. I have a last question : The body of my mail is written in HTML but the mailto do not seems to recreate it, I have all the tags in the pre-populated mail. Should I use something to encode properly ?

Comment: No. You cannot send HTML using mailto and I did suggest you did NOT use echo at all

Comment: Yes I know but that's not my code, I only make some changes to it until someone gets back, I don't want to change everything he's done… So I cannot format my mail with html ? Is there another way ? Like the /n etc.. It's just some basic things

Comment: Yes replacing all <br> to \n will work and all <li> to \n*

Comment: Thank you very much for your help over the past days ! Will do it ! have a good day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a LOT easier to read if you do not echo stuff

If you do, you need to concatenate PHP style and use the backticks for the JavaScript
NOTE: You need SINGLE quotes for the line with ${} javascript vars or the $ is interpreted:

```
echo "<script> 
      var email = \"".$maildest."\"; 
      var subject = encodeURIComponent(\"Request of the user\"); 
      var emailBody = encodeURIComponent(\`".$MAIL."\`);"
echo 'window.location = `mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${emailBody}`;';
echo "</script>";
```

Please note the backticks for the $MAIL and the last line since you likely have newlines in there

Also you need to escape spaces and special chars

Look in the console  - the mailto normally works better as a form action

Without echo:

```
?>
An OUTLOOK window opened with the informations you entered. <br/>Send the email so we can take it into account.<br/>
<script>
    var email = "<?= $maildest ?>";
    var subject = encodeURIComponent("Request of the user");
    var emailBody = encodeURIComponent(`<?= $MAIL ?>`);
    window.location = `mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${emailBody}`;
    </script>
<? 
exit(0);
?>
```

Here is a version that does not use the server:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = this.email.value,
      subject = encodeURIComponent("Request of the user"),
      elements = this.elements,
      emailTexts = [];
      
      [...elements].forEach(function(ele) {
        if (ele.type!="submit") emailTexts.push(ele.name + ":" + ele.value)
      })
    var emailBody = encodeURIComponent(emailTexts.join("\n"));
    var loc = `mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${emailBody}`;
    console.log(loc)
    window.location = loc;
  });
});
```

```html
An OUTLOOK window will open with the informations you enter. <br/>Send the email so we can take it into account.<br/>
<form id="form" ....>
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="" /><br/> Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="" /><br/> Comment: <textarea name="Comment"></textarea><br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Okay, now the mailer open something, it's so much better already. But there is no data inside the mail, only a "&body" in the subject box. I used this code : 

    `echo "<script>
        var email = \"$maildest\";
        var subject = encodeURIComponent(\"Request of the user\");
        var emailBody = encodeURIComponent(\"$MAIL\");
        window.location = 'mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${emailBody}';";
        echo "</script>";`

Comment: In your version you need `(\"".$MAIL."\")` and `var email = \"".$maildest."\"`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but that still doesn't work this way. All I get is a "&body" part of the code in the subject box of the pre-populated mail. Which of your ways should I use ? The second one ? I feel like I'm almost here with the first..

Comment: In your version you need `echo "<script> var email = \"".$maildest."\"; var subject = encodeURIComponent(\"Request of the user\"); var emailBody = encodeURIComponent(\`".$MAIL."\`); window.location = \`mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${emailBody}\`;"; echo "</script>"; ` Please note the backticks for the $MAIL and the last line since you likely have newlines in there

Comment: Now I have a HTTP ERROR 500 with the backticks. I don't understand what they are supposed to do ? Thanks so much for your help tho

Comment: Okay, it's working again, but there is still no data in my mail when i submit, only the "&body=". Seems like it can't access my php variables. Any ideas ? Maybe that's because when I submit it goes on another page ? I should run the script before ?

Comment: Sadly the source code is too long to be put in comments.. I will try to get it working but it seems like it can't access my variables, because not even the mail adress is there in the pre-populated mail.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I will try to debug it myself, you helped me already a lot, thank you for that. I might come back to you tomorrow or so if I couldn't do it myself.

Comment: Hi again mplungjan, so I debugged my code, just before the script I put an echo on every php variable that contains my mail, the subject etc.. And they show up.. So I think the problem is in the script. The variables can't be read properly, those are PHP variables, how do I link them to my javascript code ?

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea why I can't get my php variables into my script ? I'm sure this is a little something that I forgot, it drives me crazy.. :D

Comment: EITHER echo and use concatenation `"text".$var."text"` OR do NOT echo and use <?= ?>  so in your current page: `echo "<script>
        var email = \`".$maildest."\`;
        var subject = encodeURIComponent(\"Request of the user\");
        var emailBody = encodeURIComponent(\`".$MAIL."\`);
        window.location = \`mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${emailBody}\`;</script>";`

I put both in my answer. Take ONE of them, don't mix them

Comment: Yep, I tried this one already, all I get is a void mail, it doesn't populate it and in the subject I have "&body=". Maybe there is another char I need to escape that block the thing ?

Comment: my actual code is : "<script>
        var email = `".$maildest."`;
        var subject = encodeURIComponent(\"Request of the user\");
        var emailBody = encodeURIComponent(`".$MAIL."`);
        window.location = `mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${emailBody}`;
        </script>"; That is what you told me to do :/

Comment: Nah it's fine now, ut still I don't have the mail pre-populated, I even tested to show my javascript variables and it works, the problem must come from the mailto()

Comment: Can you show how it looks in the page (view source)?

Answer (score 0):

You must set event on your form, because your JS-code just working when page was rendered and not when form is submit.

```
<form action=". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . " name="form" method="POST" onsubmit="sendMail">
// Html form here
</form>
<script>
function sendMail(event) {
    // This method will stop default action of form's submit
    event.preventDefault();

    var email = "<?= $maildest ?>";
    var subject = encodeURIComponent("Request of the user");
    var emailBody = encodeURIComponent(`<?= $MAIL ?>`);
    window.location = `mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${emailBody}`;
}
</script>
```